# Random Direction in n dimensions

Tags: calculus

I am trying to write a program that generates a random direction in n dimensions. I have a random number generator that can generate a random number between 0 and 1. Let x be a random variable in [0,1]:

n=2 is very easy, let a = 2πx where a is the angle in the plane

I would like a formula in terms of x for n=3 as well as a general formula for any n if such a formula exists.

Comment: This at least answers the question for $n=3$ (though note you need to pick two random variables from $[0,1]$). http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to pick in $n$ dimensions, as described [here on Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePointPicking.html) is to pick $n$ variables that are all Gaussian in nature. That is, make a vector $\vec v = (x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n)$ where each component of the vector $x_i$ follows a [Normal distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDistribution.html):

$$
x_i \sim N(0, 1)
$$

Now, normalize the vector $\vec v = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ by dividing by the length to get a unit vector

Thus, the components of the unit vector $\vec u$ that is uniformly distributed in $n$ dimensions is

$$
\vec u = \hat v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \ldots + x_n^2}} \times \vec v
$$